# corona multi dimensional tables

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am trying to create a multi dimensional table like so

```
    answers = {}
for i = 1, #answers do
    answers[i] = { wrong = t[i], wrong2 = t2[i], right = t3[i]}
end

print(answers[1].wrong)
```

But when I try to access answers[1].wrong, I get error: attempt to index field '?' (nil value)
But when I do it this way it prints it for me

```
    answers = {
    {wrong = t[1], wrong2 = t2[1],right = t3[1]},
    {wrong = t[2], wrong2 = t2[2],right = t3[2]}
}
print("----------")
print(answers[1].wrong)
print(answers[1].wrong2)
```

Why is the first method not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
answers = {}
for i = 1, #answers do
```

`#answers` is 0. So the loop won't execute. You probably meant `#t` or something.